# Someone please help me to solve Transaction Revert problem

Tags: revert

Network: Mode Mainnet Network

Token Approve is successful but swap is not succeeding.

[image]

**Revert reason: 1TransferHelper::transferFrom: transferFrom failed**

Code:

````
const config = require('./config');

// Set up Web3 instance
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.mode.network'); // Your RPC URL here

// Set up account
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(config.privateKey);
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account); // Add account to wallet
const senderAddress = account.address;

// Set up contract instance
const routerAddress = '0x5D61c537393cf21893BE619E36fC94cd73C77DD3'; // KimRouter address
const routerABI = config.abi; // ABI for KimRouter contract
const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(routerABI, routerAddress);

// Set up USDC contract instance
const usdcAddress = '0xd988097fb8612cc24eeC14542bC03424c656005f'; // USDC token address
const usdcABI = config.erc20ABI; // ABI for ERC20 contract
const usdcContract = new web3.eth.Contract(usdcABI, usdcAddress);

// Set up transaction parameters
const amountIn = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'); // 1 USDC in Wei
const slippageTolerance = 5; // 5% slippage tolerance
const amountOutMin = web3.utils.toBN(amountIn).mul(web3.utils.toBN(100 - slippageTolerance)).div(web3.utils.toBN(100)).toString(); // Minimum amount of USDT to receive with slippage tolerance
const path = ['0xd988097fb8612cc24eeC14542bC03424c656005f', '0xf0F161fDA2712DB8b566946122a5af183995e2eD']; // USDC to USDT
const to = senderAddress;
const referrer = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; // Optional referrer address
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10; // 10 minutes from now

// Approve the router contract to spend USDC
const approveRouter = async () => {
    const txApprove = usdcContract.methods.approve(
        routerAddress,
        amountIn
    );

    try {
        console.log("Approving Router to spend USDC...");
        const gasPriceApprove = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        console.log("Gas price for approve:", gasPriceApprove);
        const gasLimitApprove = config.gasLimit; // Use configured gas limit
        console.log("Gas limit for approve:", gasLimitApprove);
        const encodedABIApprove = txApprove.encodeABI();
        const nonceApprove = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress);
        console.log("Nonce for approve:", nonceApprove);

        const txApproveData = {
            from: senderAddress,
            to: usdcAddress,
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei(config.gasPriceGwei.toString(), 'gwei'), // Convert Gwei to Wei
            gas: gasLimitApprove,
            data: encodedABIApprove,
            nonce: nonceApprove
        };

        console.log("Sending approval transaction...");
        const signedTxApprove = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txApproveData, config.privateKey);
        console.log("Signed approval transaction:", signedTxApprove);
        const txReceiptApprove = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTxApprove.rawTransaction);
        console.log('Approval transaction receipt:', txReceiptApprove);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending approval transaction:", error);
    }
};

// Execute the swap after approval
const executeSwap = async () => {
    // Create transaction object
    const txObject = routerContract.methods.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        to,
        referrer,
        deadline
    );

    try {
        console.log("Signing and sending the transaction...");
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        console.log("Gas price:", gasPrice);
        const gasLimit = config.gasLimit; // Use configured gas limit
        console.log("Gas limit:", gasLimit);
        const encodedABI = txObject.encodeABI();
        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress);
        console.log("Nonce:", nonce);

        const tx = {
            from: senderAddress,
            to: routerAddress,
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei(config.gasPriceGwei.toString(), 'gwei'), // Convert Gwei to Wei
            gas: gasLimit,
            data: encodedABI,
            nonce: nonce
        };

        console.log("Sending transaction...");
        const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, config.privateKey);
        console.log("Signed transaction:", signedTx);
        const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
        console.log('Transaction receipt:', txReceipt);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending transaction:", error);
    }
};

// Call the approve function and execute the swap
approveRouter()
    .then(executeSwap)
    .catch(console.error);```


OUTPUT:
```node "c:\Users\pc\OneDrive\DDD\Mntle Swap Bot\KImSwap\main.js"
Approving Router to spend USDC...
Gas price for approve: 1000252
Gas limit for approve: 300000
Nonce for approve: 46
Sending approval transaction...
Signed approval transaction: {
  messageHash: '0xbdf3736da75953db442d0a0a6028ebde6219a5e70f22c40ee5a049ebed15b3f0',
  v: '0x10d3a',
  r: '0x69db43289176021024c30e1fa152f10fda4144a14cc8d86f729395af02ee869d',
  s: '0x7438ae78b325e8f3c3f524866366a550d5b636e83f74d3e68d7c0a5bf4f41824',
  rawTransaction: '0xf8ac2e84b2d05e00830493e094d988097fb8612cc24eec14542bc03424c656005f80b844095ea7b30000000000000000000000005d61c537393cf21893be619e36fc94cd73c77dd30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000083010d3aa069db43289176021024c30e1fa152f10fda4144a14cc8d86f729395af02ee869da07438ae78b325e8f3c3f524866366a550d5b636e83f74d3e68d7c0a5bf4f41824',
  transactionHash: '0xe43855358960a4e9cfd11314c56263fc6382fc360fe58842c557d81f90e2019e'
}
Approval transaction receipt: {
  blockHash: '0xc5b4293693e15a3a249406c4027e75978daf703eb69ec805e10c010016f9dc85',
  blockNumber: 3466715,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 90356,
  effectiveGasPrice: 3000000000,
  from: '0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd',
  gasUsed: 26343,
  l1Fee: '0x1391cbc6c828',
  l1FeeScalar: '0.684',
  l1GasPrice: '0x2f0698a53',
  l1GasUsed: '0x9bc',
  logs: [
    {
      address: '0xd988097fb8612cc24eeC14542bC03424c656005f',
      blockHash: '0xc5b4293693e15a3a249406c4027e75978daf703eb69ec805e10c010016f9dc85',
      blockNumber: 3466715,
      data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000',
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: [Array],
      transactionHash: '0xe43855358960a4e9cfd11314c56263fc6382fc360fe58842c557d81f90e2019e',
      transactionIndex: 1,
      id: 'log_05a23d5f'
    }
  ],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000100000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0xd988097fb8612cc24eec14542bc03424c656005f',
  transactionHash: '0xe43855358960a4e9cfd11314c56263fc6382fc360fe58842c557d81f90e2019e',
  transactionIndex: 1,
  type: '0x0'
}
Signing and sending the transaction...
Gas price: 1000252
Gas limit: 300000
Nonce: 47
Sending transaction...
Signed transaction: {
  messageHash: '0x21c068c5039782476588f137a0d878ccbfdc806a8b881d0301f82020694bd811',
  v: '0x10d3a',
  r: '0x61bfc84adbc4ad36bcdd76fc3b0ba4bc79d97f0d41fbaf3443fed67f7ed43d66',
  s: '0x4fc9be6fb77f6d20388d88711d20f768ed9cb5d86bfff4a81f9334c53eecd0e5',
  rawTransaction: '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',
  transactionHash: '0xdbe7d27aa332c34900bc6847dd5e99d414690d10db87f5e1c3ef4fe2347bf6e9'
}
Error sending transaction: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xe9484bdc99a940f342870c1be950137153ad3f5158d7e7268e278e511af7db62",
  "blockNumber": 3466717,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 85324,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 3000000000,
  "from": "0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd",
  "gasUsed": 38411,
  "l1Fee": "0x1fc1dc8fd575",
  "l1FeeScalar": "0.684",
  "l1GasPrice": "0x2f0698a53",
  "l1GasUsed": "0xfcc",
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x5d61c537393cf21893be619e36fc94cd73c77dd3",
  "transactionHash": "0xdbe7d27aa332c34900bc6847dd5e99d414690d10db87f5e1c3ef4fe2347bf6e9",
  "transactionIndex": 1,
  "type": "0x0"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (c:\Users\pc\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:90:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (c:\Users\pc\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:101:21)
    at c:\Users\pc\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:396:57
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0xe9484bdc99a940f342870c1be950137153ad3f5158d7e7268e278e511af7db62',
    blockNumber: 3466717,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 85324,
    effectiveGasPrice: 3000000000,
    from: '0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd',
    gasUsed: 38411,
    l1Fee: '0x1fc1dc8fd575',
    l1FeeScalar: '0.684',
    l1GasPrice: '0x2f0698a53',
    l1GasUsed: '0xfcc',
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x5d61c537393cf21893be619e36fc94cd73c77dd3',
    transactionHash: '0xdbe7d27aa332c34900bc6847dd5e99d414690d10db87f5e1c3ef4fe2347bf6e9',
    transactionIndex: 1,
    type: '0x0'
  }
}```
````

Comment: Could it be due to that you don't have enough funds on the sending account?